# Understanding Transactions in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a small app that manages users and shifts in Android Studio.

My DB is structured as follows:

```
{
  "config" : {
    "20191108" : { // each date has a different amount of shifts under it
      "-Lt53nxPc9_lBy7EvRQa" : { // generated key for shift
        "endTime" : "00:00",
        "name" : "morning",
        "numOfEmps" : 2,
        "startTime" : "00:00",
        "users" : {
          "12345" : true,
          "54321" : true
        },
        "wage" : 0
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "12345" : {
        id: "12345",
        password : "aaaaa"
    },
    "33333" : {
        id: "33333",
        password : "bbbbb"
    },
    "54321" : {
        id: "54321",
        password : "c3c3c3"
    }
  }
}
```

The goal is to allow users to add themselves to a shift(s) of their choosing (according to constraints).

Every shift has a different `numOfEmps` field which indicates how many users can be assigned to that specific shift.

I defined two models in my app - `User` and `Shift`.

I decided to use a transaction since my app would serve multiple users and many users may decide to assign themselves to the same shift.

**My main constraint is that a user may not assign themselves to the same shift more than once and that no more than `numOfEmps` users may be assigned to a shift at any given moment.**

My code :

```
 add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Constraint No. 0
            //chosen date < today's date, user cannot assign themselves to prior shifts
            String today = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE.format(LocalDate.now());
            if(today.compareTo(dates[0]) >= 0){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot assign to prior shifts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            mDatabase.child("config").child(dates[0]).child(shift.getKey()).child("users").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                @Override
                public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

                    if(mutableData == null){
                        // Set value and report transaction success
                        mutableData.child(user.getId()).setValue(true);

                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }
                    // here I'd like to check if the user is already assigned
                    // or if numOfEmps is equal to number of children under "users" node
                    // and if so, abort transaction
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                       DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(b){
                        // update Expandable List View
                        List<User> usersList = collection.get(shift);
                        usersList.add(user);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "User already assigned to shift", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The documentation of Firebase performs transaction on a single object (Integer).

I wish to expand it to handle a list of objects (Users).

I'd appreciate help in solving this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you replace the data structure pictures with actual JSON (as text, no screenshots). That will not only make it easier for us to use it in our answer, but probably also help understand the problem (as it's unclear right now how some of the structures translate to JSON). If you have the data in the database already, you can get its JSON by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're setting the entire mutable data here:

```
mutableData.setValue(user);
```

So you're overwriting everything that's under `/users` with the value of `user`.

You'll want to only set the data for the specific user, which you can do with:

```
mutableData.child(user.getKey()).setValue(user);
```

---

A few additional notes on your approach:

- Since you're not using the `DataSnapshot` of `shiftRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(` anywhere, so I would recommend removing that listener. In general: putting a transaction inside a regular listener is a serious code-smell, as your transaction is supposed to only depend on data that you read in the transaction itself (otherwise: why would you use a transaction to begin with).
- If you want to create a push ID inside the transaction, you can just call `shiftRef.push().getKey()`. This is a pure client-side operation.
- Running a transaction on a list is typically going to lead to performance problems/contention as you add more users to the list. Consider using a data model that doesn't have this problem.
- For example: you might be better off storing the users under their ID. That way you can directly look up the user, instead of having to read all of them and search client-side (which won't scale if you get many users). So your transaction could run on `/users/$uid` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I still don't quite understand what do you mean by storing users under their ID. Wouldn't it still be a list?

Comment: Yes, but you'd use the UID as the key, instead of the `0` you have now or the push ID you were asking about. Once you use the UID as the key, you can find a user by their UID with `shiftRef.child("uidOfTheUser").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(` so you don't need to search for it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I edited my question. I'd appreciate if you'd take another look.

Comment: Not sure how to implement the part below the `if(mutableData == null)` block. I'd appreciate help

Comment: It'd help to know what doesn't work about the code you tried now.